# gae, python, onesignal --- onesignal player tags do not update on the dashboard?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, onesignal

So.. I went to update my player tags using the server api, so I sent

`{ "id": "someid", "tags":{"test1":"test2"}}`

to this onesignal url (using python and gae): https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players/someid, it returned:

```
{ 
"success": true 
}
```

So I'm wondering, why doesn't the onesignal dashboard reflect that change?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this error is due to not specifying the 'Content-Type: application/json" header. In this case the response will be 'success', since the server will not read the body of the message if the correct content type is not present.

Also, you do not need to specify the id in the message body, but there should not be any issue with doing so.

Comment: That was the case. Thanks :)